# find a string from text file in php

Tags: php, text-files, php-gettext

I have a textfile where i have written different lines. Each line contains different string values, seperated by a semicolon ; . I am trying to get the first and the second string from the lines, i however do not know how. Any solution?

PHP - right now, i am printing the whole line.

```
<?php
            $readin = file('filmer.txt');
            $ul = '<ul id="films">';
            foreach($readin as $fName){
                echo $ul.'<li>'.$fName.'</li>';
            }
        ?>
```

Text file

```
Gudfadern;*****;http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646;http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjEyMjcyNDI4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5Mzg3OA@@._V1_SX214_.jpg;Coppolas klassiska filmatisering av Mario Puzos roman om en maffiafamilj i New York. I centrum står Don Corleone, Gudfadern, men också hans söner bistår honom vid det intrikata maktspel som pågår mellan Corleone och de andra familjerna i området.

Rambo;****;http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0462499;http://ia.media-    imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTI5Mjg1MzM4NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTAyNzUzMw@@._V1_SX214_.jpg;John Rambo har i lugn och ro slagit sig ned i Thailand, nära gränsen till Burma - ett land som sedan många år tillbaka lidit av förtryck från den styrande militärjuntan. Rambo ställs plötsligt inför sitt kanske farligaste uppdrag hittills när en grupp kristna missionärer tas som gisslan av den burmesiska militären

Sagan om konungens återkomst;*****;http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167260;http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjE4MjA1NTAyMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzM1NDQyMQ@@._V1_SX214_.jpg;Gondor förbereder sig för krig mot mörkrets makter och ringen färdas långsamt med Frodo mot Mordor för att om möjligt förstöras.
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Thanks, looked it up !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/explode) to explode at your delimiter (`;`):

```
<?php
    $line = "Gudfadern;*****;http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646;http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjEyMjcyNDI4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5Mzg3OA@@._V1_SX214_.jpg;Coppolas klassiska filmatisering av Mario Puzos roman om en maffiafamilj i New York. I centrum står Don Corleone, Gudfadern, men också hans söner bistår honom vid det intrikata maktspel som pågår mellan Corleone och de andra familjerna i området.";
    $lineSplit = explode(";", $line);
    $firstAndLast = $lineSplit[0] . " - " . $lineSplit[1];
    var_dump($firstAndLast);
?>
```